# Is it possible to listen to in-DOM events with Laravel and VueJS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to emit an event from my Vue component. After the event was emitted, I want to make a redirect with Javascript or PHP. I tried it like so:

**AddressForm.vue**

```
this.$emit('addressSaved')
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<address-form
    context="create"
    @addressSaved="window.location.assign(route('customer.address.index'))"
></address-form>
```

I'm getting a console warning:

Event "addresssaved" is emitted in component  at [...]/AddressForm.vue but the handler is registered for "addressSaved". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "address-saved" instead of "addressSaved".

I've named it address-saved but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems

There are a few reasons why this won't work.

> Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates.

As the error suggests, you can't use uppercase letters for your event names as HTML attributes are `case-insensitive`.

One way to get around this issue is to use `kabab-case` i.e.

```
this.$emit('address-saved');
```

```
<address-form
    context="create"
    @address-saved="..."
></address-form>
```

The second issue would be that:

```
window.location.assign(route('customer.address.index'))
```

should be:

```
window.location.assign('{{ route('customer.address.index') }}')
```

This is because the `route` function will be evaluated on the server and the returned value is what is sent to the browser so you'd need tell blade to echo the value and then you'd also need to wrap it in quotes.

Unfortunately, this won't help either as you don't have access to the `window` object inside the HTML event listener.

---

### Solutions

There are a few alternatives you could try.

Firstly, you could simply pass the url to the component as a prop and then have the component handle the redirect.

**HTML**

```
<address-form
    context="create"
    redirect-on-save-url="{{ route('customer.address.index') }}"
></address-form>
```

Add the `redirect-on-save-prop` to the component:

```
props: ['redirect-on-save'],
//or
props: {
    'redirect-on-save': {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
},
```

Lastly, instead of your `$emit` you could have:

window.location.assign(this.redirectOnSaveUrl);

---

**Alternatively**, you could try adding your own `$redirect` method to Vue:

```
Vue.prototype.$redirect = function (url) {
    window.location.assign(url);
};
```

Then your HTML could be:

```
<address-form
    context="create"
    @address-saved="$redirect('{{ route('customer.address.index') }}')"
></address-form>
```

Comment: `route` won't resolve here either...it's a laravel function, not javascript.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The `route` function is being used in a blade file so it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Btw, I'm using tightenco Ziggy, so I can use the route function in Javascript too. Forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put your event inside a v-on

```
<address-form
    context="create"
    v-on="{
        addressSaved: function(){ 
           window.location.assign(route('customer.address.index'))
        }
    }"
/>
```